# BESadmin password change

Tags: bes

I need to log onto Blackberry Enterprise server but dont have the password.

I have done the following:

1. Change the BESadmin password in AD
2. Logon to the BES using the new password
3. Change the password assigned to all the Blackberry Services
4. Stop and then start the BAS services.

But im still unable to log in.

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the Administration Server, see the various answers here:  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Enterprise-Server/BAS-first-login-forgot-my-password-How-can-I-reset-or-change/td-p/254188

They explain how to reset the password using various SQL methods or scripts.

However, if your BES server isn't backed up (including BES database and settings) then I would strongly recommend you call BB support.  I wouldn't want a bunch of users (usually execs and sales people are still on BB's...lol) calling me upset that their mail suddenly stopped working.